# What is param of myMethod() in myContract.methods.myMethod().call(options[, callback])

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have this in Solidity

```
function getOrder(
        bool _orderType,
        bytes32 _id
    )
        public
        view
        returns (
            address maker,
            uint have,
            uint want,
            bytes32 prevID,
            bytes32 nextID
        )
```

I want to find what will return in block 1. I use this

```
myContract.methods.getOrder().call(undefined, 1)
```

What parameter should I pass into getOreder() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first parameters, you should pass either `true` or `false`.

As the second parameter, you should pass:

- `Web3.fromAscii("someID")` if you're using web3.js v0.x
- `Web3.utils.asciiToHex("someID")` if you're using web3.js v1.x